# How to install red5 on heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, heroku, red5, audio-recording

I am trying to build an audio recorder and have 3 questions:

1. Is red5 enough for building an audio recorder? No need for a flash recorder or something?
2. How can I install red5 on heroku server?
3. Is there a tutorial for audio recorder in rails?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - you can't.

The Heroku platform is 'as is' - you can only install gems as specified in your gemfile.

Comment: so i can't i build audio recorder in rails app? you have a gem for me who can do it? thanks...

Comment: I answered the question - you can't install Red5 on Heroku. That's not to say you couldn't install it on another Rails host, just not Heroku. But there are no red5 gems on RubyGems - http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=red5

Comment: a down vote for answering the question - what's with that? huh?

Comment: no idea I'm afraid, only familiar with Heroku. But don't see why not. Red5 is just a media server. So some kind of flash app to stream into Red5 would seem perfectly possible.

Comment: also - this question was just asked, may be worth watching it for answers too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109343/audio-recorder-question

Answer (score 0):

Uff, hard to tell, actually.
1) Is red5 enough for building an audio recorder? No need for a flash recorder or something?

Right, with "Red5" you have the streaming server. Then, you need recorder, in flash or another program that use the RTMP stream protocol. There are several examples in Red5 [svn](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/) and [here](http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/)

2) How can I install red5 on heroku server?

You can try modifying the Red5 server java srcs (e.g. the ANT build to Maven) and upload it to the Heroku Java Cedar stack. I shouldn't be imposible to port to it.

3) Is there a tutorial for audio recorder in rails?

Don't know of any. Currently, I'm working on a rails app with video recording/playing capabilities using a Red5 server and Red5Recorder. If it works, I can post my experiences somewhere :)

Good luck

Comment: Any luck?  I'm embarking on a similar project :)

Comment: Nop, sorry. The project was cancelled :)