# Audio recorder question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recorder

looking for a free audio recorder so user will be able to record him self and the record will be uploaded to the server (by Rails).

Is there something I can use to achieve this?

Comment: It is not about Rails. It is more about Flash, Red5 or something like this. Rails can't record sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so easy. There is no ready solution. You should setup your own media server, then pass to it sound (via Flash, I believe), record this sound on server and then store somewhere on server.

> http://www.red5.org/

**UPD**

Similar question: [How to record voice files using PHP, FLASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065797/how-to-record-voice-files-using-php-flash)

Comment: Hi fl00r, thank you very much. Unfortunately I use heroku so as I understood I can't install red5. What can I do? Thank you very much!

Comment: @AdamGold, So you can do nothing

Comment: Can't add voice recording feature on Heroku?

Comment: @AdamGold, no, there is no any solutions out of the box for Heroku. You can write your own media server on Ruby.

Comment: @AdamGold you can use amazon's S3 only for the voice recorder upload thing. and can get the audio files from there on heroku.

Comment: sad when reading this.... geeez....
so where do we shall implement red5 opensource into the server other than heroku (for open/public non commercial purposes) ?